# And operator of two sets in MongoDB for Laravel using Jenssegers

Tags: mongodb, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to mimick a MongoDB query in Laravel using the Jenssegers Eloquent model.

The query is this one:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({
    $and : [
       {$or : [
           { "user.gender" : "male"},
           {"user.location" : "NYC"}
       ]}, 
       {$and : [
           {"user.name" : "User Name"},
           {"user.id" : "10143224362247922"}
       ]}
   ]
})
```

It is an AND of two sets, being the first set being an OR of values while the second set being another AND of values.

I'm using the following query:

```
$query = array(
  '$and' => array(
    '$or' => array(
      "user.gender" => "male",
      "user.location" => "NYC",
     ),
     '$and' => array(
       "user.name" => "User Name",
       "user.id" => "10143224362247922",
     ),
   )
 );

$cursor = User::raw()->find($query, array(
  "_id" => false,
));
```

But I get the error: *Can't canonicalize query: BadValue and needs an array*

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP syntax for representing true arrays is wrong in a couple of places here, but primarily you have yourself tied in unnecessary knots because your initial understanding of the MongoDB query syntax missed some points in the beginning.

Though your initial query does work both [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operations you use are not necessary because all arguments in a MongoDB query are considered to be an "implicit and" operation unless stated otherwise.

It can therefore be more efficiently written as:

```js
db.getCollection('users').find({
    "$or" : [
        { "user.gender" : "male"},
        { "user.location" : "NYC"}
    ], 
    "user.name" : "User Name",
    "user.id" : "10143224362247922"
})
```

Or in PHP syntax like so:

```php
$query = array(
    '$or' => array(
         array( "user.gender" => "male" ),
         array( "user.location" => "NYC" )
     ),
    array( "user.name" => "User Name" ),
    array( "user.id" => "10143224362247922" )
);
```

However there is still to my mind one problem here. If your intent is to match these properties in a single element of an array then your query does not work.

The way matching with arrays works with MongoDB is that the conditions can match **any** array element of the array. So the conditions may be present in the array items, but not necessarily all in the **one** element.

For this case you use [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) which basically applies it's own set of query conditions to each array element as the test. Only when all the conditions are met for that particular element is the element ( and therefore document ) considered to be a match:

```js
db.getCollection('users').find({
    "user": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "$or": [
                { "gender" : "male"},
                { "location" : "NYC" }
            ],
            "name" : "User Name",
            "id" : "10143224362247922"
        }
    }
})
```

And for PHP:

```php
$query = array(
    'user' => array(
        '$elemMatch' => array(
            '$or' => array(
                array( "gender" => "male" ),
                array( "location" => "NYC" )
            ),
            array( "name" => "User Name" ),
            array( "id" => "10143224362247922" )
         )
    )
);
```

So the ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) you are using is fine for "single" conditions on array elements. But for "multiple" conditions use [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) instead.

---

Also on a related note, if you are having trouble converting the typical JSON syntax examples you find that work with the shell then you can always test your PHP structures with [**`json_encode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). That at least shows you the JSON serialization so you can compare. Also a decent tool for logging, which IMHO is the best initial way to debug in your application.